# Recreate switches similar to Android 12 settings

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

Android 12's settings' switches now look like this,

[image: Android 12's settings screenshot]

which its code is here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/c4cc279a2a32e6b5dfac9af4a16a4d98def82a22/res/xml/configure_notification_settings.xml#133

but neither `androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat` nor `androidx.preference.SwitchPreference` look like this in my app with updated material library (1.5.0, Material 3),

[image: switches in my app]

How can I have the same looking (and feeling, animation, etc) switches at least in Android 12 or how Android is doing it for itself? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily customize your switches to look like these.

In `styles.xml` add this :

```
<style name="App.Switches" parent="Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="track">@drawable/switch_track</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_thumb</item>
</style>
```

`switch_track.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="56dp" />
        <size
            android:width="64dp"
            android:height="28dp" />
    </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

`switch_thumb.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <size
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

In the end add this line in your app's main theme to apply this style to all the switches in your app :

```
<item name="switchStyle">@style/App.Switches</item>
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I now have found how that is done on Android, putting its link here so that may help others https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/172f4ac/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsTheme/res/values-v31/styles.xml#30 

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/172f4ac/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsTheme/res/drawable-v31/settingslib_switch_track.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/172f4ac/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsTheme/res/drawable-v31/settingslib_switch_thumb.xml

Answer (score 2):

As Material 1.7.0 the suggestion is to use [MaterialSwitch](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/072578d/lib/java/com/google/android/material/materialswitch/MaterialSwitch.java) which more or less is like this by default,

[image]

Comment: You cannot include such a control in the preference files, what are you on about?

Comment: In face the above screenshot was from preferences screen, I've explained here how https://stackoverflow.com/a/73782598