# New Android 12+ MaterialSwitch and androidx.preference

Tags: android, styles, android-preferences, switchpreference, material-you

So i'm updating my apps to fully support Monet and Material You guidelines, and the official site mentions [a new design for the switches](https://m3.material.io/components/switch/implementation). I used it, and that's the result:

[image: MaterialSwitch in the app]

I have a preference screen using Androidx preferences library, latest version available at the time of writing, and the only way i found to theme the switches (except the manual theming, which makes no sense) is to use this line in the app's theme:

```
<item name="switchStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch</item>
```

And using SwitchPreferenceCompat (it doesn't work in the regular SwitchPreference) this is what i get:

[image: Switch in preference]

Regardless of the width (which is different, but can be changed) the disabled state is completely different and doesn't match the rest of the app. **Why**? and most importantly, why do they suggest to use a library which:

1. Doesn't support Material You out of the box
2. Doesn't support any new Material3 component
3. It's hard to properly customize in general

?

I don't want to be too critical, but this is out of my understanding.

EDIT: at the moment, i'm using switchCompat everywhere, to make the app uniform. Looking at the system apps, i can find 4 different type of switches: a custom switch similar to the second screenshot, the old one and the two types in this question. That's hella confusing.

Comment: I cannot comment due to low karma, but I just wanted to let you know I have filed a bug report to Google about this on their IssueTracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247430819

It's been assigned, so hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I understand Google stance on this, they don't want to make `androidx.*` packages dependent to Material library itself, maybe they should provide a separate preference package but this time with fully Material widgets.

In order to have the brand new MaterialSwitch of Material 1.7.0 with preference, I've overridden its `widgetLayout` with a custom layout by `android:widgetLayout="@layout/preference_material_switch"` (in fact I applied that programmatically like `.widgetLayoutResource = R.layout.preference_material_switch`) and put the following on preference_material_switch.xml layout file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Derived from https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/8cb282cc/preference/preference/res/layout/preference_widget_switch_compat.xml -->
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Update: Alternative solution rather than adding `android:widgetLayout=` to each switch is to add the following to your base theme,

```
         <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppPreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

Then adding the following styles also,

```
    <style name="AppPreferenceThemeOverlay" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
        <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/AppSwitchPreference</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppSwitchPreference" parent="@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat.Material">
        <item name="widgetLayout">@layout/preference_material_switch</item>
    </style>
```

And here is the result,

[image]

Comment: This is a bad solution as the title doesn't show at all.

Comment: You've probably overridden `layout` instead `widgetLayout` as this solution shows the title here for weeks with no issue.

Comment: **My mistake, your solution does indeed work.**

Comment: Well, i don't like to override stuff normally, but seems like that's my only option as of now. Thanks!

Comment: Notice for everyone, remember to use SwitchPreferenceCompat or it will not work!

Comment: Thaks a lot ! I've been trying to get this result since yesterday. Tried a lot of "official" way with theme configuration without luck. You saved me

Answer (score 3):

*The same problem, After seeing these replies, I'm thinking to build the settings fragment without androidx.preference.*

**[MKevin3 said:](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/x8vl9m/comment/inl7jg7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)**

> I hate the provided Android preferences setup and look. So many times they changed the rules and broke what I had.
>
> Not that this helps you probably but I just did my own to avoid all the headaches and I am in full control of the look. If push comes to hove you might consider doing this as well instead of fighting the "Android Way".

**[sc00ty said:](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/x8vl9m/comment/inlbj1d/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)**

> I gave up trying to use their widgets and fragments. It was so much less of a headache to spend a little time making my own compound widgets for each setting type.

Comment: That's true, but in this particular case we also have a difference between the material3 switch and the material3 components switch, independently from the library. And, again, that's terribly confusing