# How to use material 3 Switch in PreferenceFragmentCompat programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences, material-components-android

SwitchPreferenceCompat still retains the old Switch style, I know to be able to style it Material 3 in the following way:

theme.xml

```xml
<style name="Theme.Material3.Preference" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/MaterialPreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialPreferenceThemeOverlay" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat</item>
</style>

<style name="Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat" parent="Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat.Material">
    <item name="android:widgetLayout">@layout/preference_widget_material_switch</item>
</style>
```

preference_widget_material_switch.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

setting.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_key"
        android:summary="Preference Summary"
        android:title="Preference Title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]
But for some reason I have to build PreferenceFragment programmatically like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    val context = preferenceManager.context
    val screen = preferenceManager.createPreferenceScreen(context)
    val notificationPreference = SwitchPreferenceCompat(context).apply {
        key = "pref_key"
        title = "Preference Title"
        summary="Preference Summary"
    }
    screen.addPreference(notificationPreference)
    preferenceScreen = screen
}
```

At this time, even if I have the ThemeOverlay above, the style of the switch is still old.
[image]
**So, how to use material 3 Switch in PreferenceFragmentCompat programmatically?**

*I'm guessing it might be possible to set the theme of SwitchPreferenceCompat via one of its constructors, but I don't know about Views, so can you guys help me?*

```java
SwitchPreferenceCompat(@NonNull Context context)  

SwitchPreferenceCompat(
    @NonNull Context context,
    @Nullable AttributeSet attrs
)  

SwitchPreferenceCompat(
    @NonNull Context context,
    @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,
    int defStyleAttr
)  

SwitchPreferenceCompat(
    @NonNull Context context,
    @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,
    int defStyleAttr,
    int defStyleRes
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding your `SwitchPreference` to your preferences screen you can use `setWidgetLayout()` where you pass the `resId` of your `preference_widget_material_switch.xml` layout.

Or if it doesn't work (like in my project) you can create a custom View that extends `SwitchPreferenceCompat` and it's in its init block that you set the layout resource id for the switch widget to use.

```
class MaterialSwitchPreference(context: Context): SwitchPreferenceCompat(context) {

    init {
        widgetLayoutResource = R.layout.preference_widget_material_switch
    }

}
```

Then just use this `MaterialSwitchPreference` instead of the usual `SwitchPrefernce`.

Note: I'm a beginner and I don't know if extending a View for such a little thing is a good practice, but it works fine for me...

Comment: Call setWidgetLayout() on an instance of SwitchPreferenceCompat working fine for me.

Comment: @bqliang Ok, the problem in my project was maybe cause I use PreferenceDataStore... So I've edited the answer, please review it, and maybe set it to accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to add a new class for the Material 3 switches, you can override the used layout of the usual `SwitchPreferenceCompat` by following 2 simple steps:

https://medium.com/@cyb3rko/simple-implementation-of-material-3-switches-in-preferences-4b83ea3202d1

---

1. Add the new switch layout to your project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Derived from https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/005e9694795cee9a42375d80b0d813af9e700ac1/preference/preference/res/layout/preference_widget_switch_compat.xml -->
<!-- Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73782598/9077356 -->
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null" />
```

2. Override the switch theming in your app theming:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    
    <style name="Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat" parent="@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat.Material"
           tools:ignore="ResourceCycle">
        <item name="widgetLayout">@layout/preference_switch</item>
    </style>
    
    ...
</resources>
```

---

Now you can just use the usual `SwitchPreferenceCompat` in your preference screen like before:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:title="Material 3 switch"
        app:summary="This is the new Material 3 switch" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```